# contact 7 WordPress implement pixel or event

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, facebook-pixel

Contact form 7 (WordPress) don't fire FB event

I added pixel code to the "additional settings" but nothing happened 
[image]

The code I wrote fit to what [Contact Form 7 custom DOM event](https://contactform7.com/dom-events/) required

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {

<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
  !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
  {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
  n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
  if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
  n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
  t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
  'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
  fbq('init', '18015239334xxxxx[![enter image description here][1]][1]');
  fbq('track', 'lead_sent');
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
  src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=18015239334xxxx&ev=lead_sent&noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->

}, false );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the code in yours **functions.php**

The example below is for Google Tag Manager conversion:

```js
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'mycustom_wp_footer' );
 
function mycustom_wp_footer() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
   dataLayer.push({
  'conversionValue': 1,
  'event': 'conversao'
});

}, false );
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7invalid', function( event ) {
   dataLayer.push({
  'conversionValue': 1,
  'event': 'invalido'
});

}, false );
</script>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read documentation...

https://contactform7.com/additional-settings/

"You can include additional settings to each contact form by adding code snippets in the **specific format** into the Additional Settings field in the contact form’s edit screen."

You can't use typical javascript.